# Spring Boot REST endpoint connection not being released

Tags: rest, spring-boot

I have created Spring boot (2.1.4.RELEASE) REST endpoint to GET some data from the server. When I call this endpoint from the browser, I see the JSON in the browser window but I notice that the the spinner in fav icon is going on for 60 seconds. When i look at the network tab, I never see the response section for the request. After 60 seconds, it says that it failed. When I walk through the code in debugger, I see that data is being returned from the controller and when I 'play' the rest of the stack everything completes (thread that is being assigned to serve the request) I am kind of puzzled what's causing this behavior.

```
@GetMapping(path="/recipes")
public ResponseEntity<Collection<HpManifest>> getRecipes() {
    ResponseEntity<Collection<HpManifest>> response = hpService.getRecipes();
    return response;
}

public ResponseEntity<Collection<HpManifest>> getRecipes() {
    logger.info("Retrieving recipes from");

    UriComponentsBuilder builder = 
            UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(endpointManifests)
                .queryParam("type", HpManifestType.RECIPE.getType());

    logger.info("REST endpoint: " + builder.toUriString());

    ResponseEntity<Collection<HpManifest>> recipes = restTemplate.exchange(
            builder.toUriString(), 
            HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<Collection<HpManifest>>() {});

    logger.info("recipes are:");
    recipes.getBody().forEach(r -> logger.info(r.toString()));

    return recipes;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue just the other day.  In my case it turned out to be that  `recipes` (returned from the `restTemplate.exchange` method) contained a `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` in the headers and then when you return `recipes`, your spring framework is probably also including a `Content-Length` header.  The combination of these two headers in a response to a browser can cause issues because the browser thinks it's getting chunked data back, but in reality it is not.  I suggest making a new `ResponseEntity` from your `recipes` variable along the lines of:

```
return ResponseEntity.status(recipes.getStatusCode()).body(response.getBody());
```

Alternatively you could maybe force your spring framework to return chunked data, but I think that is not the right way to go.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to return a new response entity and things worked without seeing your response. But with your explanation, it makes sense why it behaves that way too. Thanks again.